# Why it is still showing 403 forbidden in the response

Tags: java, webapi, restful-authentication

When i post a request with the accurate body type, it was showing 403 forbidden error.

```
package com.WebAuthentication.DemoProject.security.config;

import com.WebAuthentication.DemoProject.appuser.AppUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v*/**").permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }

}
```

###RegistrationController

```
package com.WebAuthentication.DemoProject.registration;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;
    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request){

        return "It works";
    }

}
```

The build was successfull and the console shows no error.
The Response must be It works.

```
package com.WebAuthentication.DemoProject.appuser;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "User with email %s not found";
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(()->
                    new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE,email)));

    }
}
```

The build was successfull and the console shows no error.
The Response must be It works.
Help me out.

I tried this  but not worked

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests((auth) -> auth
            .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**").permitAll() // Allow unrestricted access to these endpoints
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // Require authentication for any other request
        );

    return http.build();
}
```